# PowerShell to import promoted results into SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, promoted-results, best-bets

My organisation is migrating from SP2010 to SPO and would like to use PowerShell to migrate the best bets from SP2010 to promoted results in SPO.

I currently have a csv file of promoted results and the URLs I would like them to point to. I want to use PowerShell to import them into my SPO site collection. Please suggest if there are any PowerShell scripts for importing promoted results.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if below helps... Ref [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d17a907e-49d5-4237-a68c-d82048533c8c/creating-bestbets-via-powershell-how-do-i-set-the-various-options?forum=sharepointadmin)

```
    $siteUrl = "http://sandbox0391"
$resultSourceName = "Local SharePoint Results"

$web = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "SBX Search Service Application 2"
$queryRuleManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Rules.QueryRuleManager($ssa)
$site = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
$searchOwner = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchObjectOwner -ArgumentList  @([Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchObjectLevel]::Ssa,$site.RootWeb)
$searchObjectFilter = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchObjectFilter($searchOwner)
$federationManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Query.FederationManager($ssa)
$resultSource = $federationManager.GetSourceByName($resultSourceName,$searchOwner)
$queryRules = $queryRuleManager.GetQueryRules($searchObjectFilter)
$promotedResultCollection = $ssa.GetBestBets($searchObjectFilter)

function CreatePromotedResult([string]$title, [string]$url, [string]$description)
{
        Write-Host "Creating Promoted Result .." $title
        $queryRule = $queryRules.CreateQueryRule($title,$null,$null,$true)
        [string[]]$keywords = $title.split(' ')
        $keywords += $title     
        $keywordCondition = $queryRule.QueryConditions.CreateKeywordCondition($keywords,$false)
        $queryAction = $queryRule.CreateQueryAction([Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Rules.QueryActionType]::AssignBestBet)
        #PromotedResult = BestBet
        $promotedResult = $promotedResultCollection.CreateBestBet($title, $url, $description, $false)
        #Map the best bet to the query action
        $queryAction.BestBetIds.Add($promotedResult.Id);
        #Update the query rule
        $queryRule.Update()
        $queryRule = $null  
        Write-Host "Created Promoted Result for" $title "Finished"      
}

CreatePromotedResult "Benefits" "https://URL.com/Pages/OpenEnrollment.aspx" "Benefits page!"
```